# ORDER BY not giving max digital

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, sql-order-by, sqlitestudio

I'm using SQLite Studio and need to show 20 largsest numbers in SUM_D, but it get me "999,987" as biggest. At least i have "1 925,886", but it isn't show.

```
SELECT NAME, SUM_D FROM borg_1 ORDER BY SUM_D DESC LIMIT 20;
```

[so here u could see my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZdOo.png) and
[my outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sj2DM.png)

[my structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivFBP.png)

Comment: Store your data as numbers rather than as strings.

Comment: `1 925,886` is a string and not a number.  Strings are sorted alphabetically.

Comment: SUM_D  is INT type, i added sctruture

Comment: if i misunderstood how i could possibly fix it

Comment: SQLiite's data typing system is quite different than other databases. Check this: https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html The definition of a column as INT does not prevent the insertion of any data type in that column. So you inserted non numeric values in the column and you can't sort numerically.

Comment: i changed all INT types to INTEGER but nothing changed in outcome

Comment: Do you understand that `999,987` and `1 925,886` are not numbers and whatever data type you choose for the column they will never be considered as numbers?

Comment: yeah, but what could i do with this, it was imported from .csv file

Comment: Is the `,` in the values the decimal separator?

Comment: In csv file - yes, all numbers are divided with `,`  if i change them all on `.` and import it one more time could it help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you don't store numbers in the column `SUM_D` but strings.
Update the table so that all `,` are replaced with the `.` as the decimal separator and all spaces are removed:

```
UPDATE borg_1
SET SUM_D = REPLACE(REPLACE(SUM_D, ' ', ''), ',', '.')
```

Then your query will work fine.

Note that you should have defined the column's data type as `REAL` and not `INT` since you want to store floating point numbers, but this alone would not solve your problem.

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=063f2ab1ceeafdd119ad84650e7a3474).

Comment: You are my hero! Thank you a lot

Answer (score -1):

Try to use `CAST` expression:

```
SELECT NAME, SUM_D FROM borg_1 ORDER BY cast(replace(replace(SUM_D, ' ','' ),',','.') as NUMERIC) DESC LIMIT 20;
```

because sqlite can consider that SUM_D contains string value:

1. Because your value have while spaces.
2. You use `,` instead `.`

You have other option: format your numbers before inserting to DB.

Comment: 999.987 become second and 999,746 first, other values are at the same place and order

Comment: @Jeki4an Look like the problem with format of value : 1) in contains white spaces, 2) contains commas instead dots  . Id change query to replace this symbols, please try again